# How to use jar for open with in Windows 7

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have a executable jar file. This executable jar file accepts parameter to work with.

I'm trying to figure out how to set this up as "Open with...".

To be very specific I'm using [yEd editor](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) and it creates files with extension graphml, so I'd like to setup yEd as a file to open such files...

I tried to create yed.bat file as

```
start javaw -jar yed.jar %1
```

but when I try to open such file, I'm getting error from JVM:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile yed.jar
```

[image: Error: Unable to access jarfile yed.jar]

Comment: Looks to me like either a path issue or a permission issue. Have you tried giving it the full path instead of just `yed.jar`?

Comment: @Turing85 Oh, I was testing the bat always in same folder, that's it... Can you make it an answer, I'll accept it ;-)

Comment: I found no info about the topic - "how to use jar as open with", that's why I want to keep it. If I'll answer my question I'll get your credit for it (if any).